# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'ip' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

не помогло
and others didnt help? i work with phpmyAdmin? help me(другие случаи не работают)
когда была локальная базаданных, все работало нормально, вот ссылка

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/f4xbGS7taF";
```

Comment: Переведите, пж-та, вопрос на русский. И отформатируйте, чтобы было видно где проблемный код, а где пояснения к нему.

Comment: Откуда нам знать работаете ли вы с phpMyAdmin и помог ли вам этот или другие запросы? Вам, очевидно, виднее.

Comment: я все исправил, сорри я думал я на английском стаке

Comment: я исправил в плане текста, ошибка у меня таже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по `String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/f4xbGS7taF";` к БД вы подключаетесь не с локального хоста.

Для того, чтоб иметь возможность подключаться к БД удаленно, вам нужно:

1. Включить прослушку порта 3306 не только на локальном хосте. Делается это в файле настройке mysql сервера. У меня например это в файле

nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

```
...
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
...
```

Замените 127.0.0.1 на 0.0.0.0
После этого перегрузите mysql сервер.

2. Не надо разрешать даже самому доверенному приложению подключаться из под root. Вы все равно настраиваете подключение к БД, так создайте отдельного пользователя для этого.

Строчкой `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'...` вы даете права для пользователя, подключающегося с localhost'а.

Сделайте так:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdb.* TO 'user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/yourdb

и у вас все заработает.

P.S. вместо 'user'@'%' можно указать IP вашего приложения, например 'user'@'192.168.0.1'